# UserControl (Add listview GridViewColumn from another user control)

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles

I want to add a `GridViewColumn` to a `ListView` which resides in a `UserControl` from another Windows screen (Parent).

Example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListViewUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="100" Width="300">
    <Canvas>
        <StackPanel Height="100" Width="300" Name="listViewHolder">
            <ListView Name="LstView"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

I want to use this user control in Windows.

**How can I change the ListView Style, ItemContainerStyle, or add GridViewColumn?**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationListView.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window2" Height="470" Width="882">
    <Canvas>
        <my1:ListViewNavigation Name="navCtrl"
                                xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:UsrControls;assembly=UsrControls"
                                Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Height="233" Width="493">
        </my1:ListViewNavigation>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Please let me know is there any other way to design this scenario.

Regards,

Jegan

Answer (score 0):

We can use dependency property to pass the property to child controls...

Regards
Jegan